# XSLT concatenating values with conditions

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and would like to concatenate text values before and after AppliedLanguage="$ID/Japanese" below only when HorizontalScale value of the nodes are identical like HorizontalScale="98".

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ParagraphStyleRange>
    <CharacterStyleRange PointSize="7">
        <Content>A</Content>
    </CharacterStyleRange>
    <CharacterStyleRange HorizontalScale="98">
        <Content>B</Content>
    </CharacterStyleRange>
    <CharacterStyleRange HorizontalScale="98" AppliedLanguage="$ID/Japanese">
        <Content>C</Content>
    </CharacterStyleRange>
    <CharacterStyleRange HorizontalScale="98">
        <Content>D</Content>
    </CharacterStyleRange>
    <CharacterStyleRange HorizontalScale="98" AppliedLanguage="$ID/Japanese">
        <Content>E</Content>
    </CharacterStyleRange>
    <CharacterStyleRange HorizontalScale="98">
        <Content>F</Content>
    </CharacterStyleRange>
    <CharacterStyleRange>
        <Br />
    </CharacterStyleRange>
</ParagraphStyleRange>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ParagraphStyleRange>
    <CharacterStyleRange PointSize="7">
        <Content>A</Content>
    </CharacterStyleRange>
    <CharacterStyleRange HorizontalScale="98" AppliedLanguage="$ID/Japanese">
        <Content>BCDEF</Content>
    </CharacterStyleRange>
    <CharacterStyleRange>
        <Br />
    </CharacterStyleRange>
</ParagraphStyleRange>
```

How do we do this with XSLT?

Comment: Tell us which version of XSLT you use or which XSLT processor. Also a single example doesn't explain the problem, what would happen if there were `<CharacterStyleRange HorizontalScale="98" AppliedLanguage="$ID/English"><Content>D</Content>` in between the Japanese one, which result would you want?

Comment: Welcome to SO: [What does it mean to accept an
answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="CharacterStyleRange[@HorizontalScale = '98'][1]">
        <CharacterStyleRange HorizontalScale="98" AppliedLanguage="$ID/Japanese">
            <Content>
                <xsl:value-of select="//CharacterStyleRange[@HorizontalScale = '98']/Content"/>
            </Content>
        </CharacterStyleRange>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="CharacterStyleRange[@HorizontalScale = '98'][position() != [1]]"/> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It's done using XSLT 2.0 and tested with Saxon-EE/HE/PE 9.9.1.7. First we use the identity template to copy input unchanged. Then we match the first instance of `<CharacterStyleRange HorizontalScale="98">`, and output the text of all `<Content>` elements of this kind:

```xml
<xsl:template match="CharacterStyleRange[@HorizontalScale = '98'][1]">
  <CharacterStyleRange HorizontalScale="98" AppliedLanguage="$ID/Japanese">
    <Content>
      <xsl:value-of select="//CharacterStyleRange[@HorizontalScale = '98']/Content"/>
    </Content>
  </CharacterStyleRange>
</xsl:template>
```

Finally, when encountering any instance of `<CharacterStyleRange HorizontalScale="98">` which **is not the first**, we do nothing.

```xml
<xsl:template match="CharacterStyleRange[@HorizontalScale = '98'][position() != [1]]"/>
```